# How to change only image color in login screen using css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have an username and password input field with PNG image icon as per screenshot. I want to change username or password PNG image color. My requirement is to change image only color to white instead black(transform image color).How to achieve using CSS. I have tried the below CSS. But it is changing complete background color of username or password input box. I don't want to change back ground color of input field. Background color of input field should be same as shown in screenshot.

```html
filter: invert(100%) sepia(16%) saturate(7463%) hue-rotate(222deg) brightness(119%) contrast(115%);
```

here is my username field code look like this. I am using react application

```html
        <Field
              id={"userName"}
              name={"userName"}              
              component={FormInput}            
              placeholder="User Name"      
              style={{
                backgroundImage: "url(UserName.png)",
                backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                backgroundPosition: "-5px 8px",
                padding: "9px 20px 0px 20px",
                backgroundSize: "25px",                
                borderTop: "none",
                borderLeft: "none",
                borderRight: "none",
                maxWidth: "440px",
              }}              
            />
```

[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15LuM.png)

Comment: I can't see a screenshot, and please create a runnable snippet so we can see the problem - read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to simply change the color of the png with photoshop or a free alternative image editor

Comment: I can not use this way  because My application is applying for different color theme. For white background i need black color image and for black background i need white color image.

Comment: You could get .svg icons instead of png, and then use css stroke property to change the color when needed. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke/